# Select max data from row for every foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have a MySQL Database, with some tables.

With this query:

```
SELECT anagrafe.MARCHIO, anagrafe.BOLO, anagrafe.NUMERO_AZIENDALE, visite.COLLOCAZIONE, visite.DATA_PREVISTA_PARTO, visite.DATA_VISITA  
FROM anagrafe LEFT JOIN visite USING(NUMERO_AZIENDALE) 
WHERE visite.STATO_VISITA ='Gravida' AND visite.DATA_PREVISTA_PARTO > '2017-04-01'
```

I get this:
[image]
but I need only the row that have the max(DATA_VISITA) for every NUMERO_AZIENDALE (see the red)

NUMERO_AZIENDALE is a foreign key for anagrafe (a table) and a part of primary key for visite (a table). 
The primary key is composed by NUMERO_AZIENDALE and ID (not shown here)

I tried with GROUP BY NUMERO_AZIENDALE but visite.COLLOCAZIONE is not shown properlly, that is, the query show the value of the row that I don't need

Comment: what do You mean by 'visite.COLLOCAZIONE is not shown properlly' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to repeat the `JOIN`.  This should be a simpler way to do what you want:

```
SELECT a.MARCHIO, a.BOLO, a.NUMERO_AZIENDALE,
       v.COLLOCAZIONE, v.DATA_PREVISTA_PARTO, v.DATA_VISITA  
FROM anagrafe a JOIN
     visite v
     USING (NUMERO_AZIENDALE) 
WHERE v.STATO_VISITA ='Gravida' AND
      v.DATA_PREVISTA_PARTO > '2017-04-01' AND
      v.DATA_VISITA = (SELECT MAX(v2.DATA_VISITA)
                       FROM visite v2
                       WHERE v2.NUMERO_AZIENDALE = v.NUMERO_AZIENDALE AND
                             v2.STATO_VISITA = v.STATO_VISITA AND
                             v2.DATA_PREVISTA_PARTO > '2017-04-01'
                      );
```

Notes:

- The `WHERE` clause turns the `LEFT JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN`, so don't be misleading by calling it a `LEFT JOIN`.
- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- This assumes that the `visite` is the one you want for the maximum value.
- You can phrase this logic using `IN` and tuples or using a `JOIN` to an aggregated query in the `FROM` clause.  The key point is that the additional `JOIN` is not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a in clause for a tuple based on NUMERO_AZIENDALE and DATA_VISITA   group by NUMERO_AZIENDALE

```
  SELECT  anagrafe.MARCHIO, anagrafe.BOLO, anagrafe.NUMERO_AZIENDALE,
           visite.COLLOCAZIONE, visite.DATA_PREVISTA_PARTO, visite.DATA_VISITA 
  FROM anagrafe LEFT JOIN visite USING(NUMERO_AZIENDALE
  WHERE visite.STATO_VISITA ='Gravida' AND visite.DATA_PREVISTA_PARTO > '2017-04-01'
  AND (anagrafe.NUMERO_AZIENDALE, visite.DATA_VISITA ) IN 
  ( 
  SELECT  anagrafe.NUMERO_AZIENDALE, max(visite.DATA_VISITA)  
  FROM anagrafe LEFT JOIN visite USING(NUMERO_AZIENDALE) 
  WHERE visite.STATO_VISITA ='Gravida' 
    AND visite.DATA_PREVISTA_PARTO > '2017-04-01'
    GROUP BY anagrafe.NUMERO_AZIENDALE
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use correlated subquery like this:

```
SELECT anagrafe.MARCHIO, anagrafe.BOLO, anagrafe.NUMERO_AZIENDALE, visite.COLLOCAZIONE, visite.DATA_PREVISTA_PARTO, visite.DATA_VISITA  
FROM anagrafe LEFT JOIN visite USING(NUMERO_AZIENDALE) 
WHERE 
visite.STATO_VISITA ='Gravida' 
AND visite.DATA_PREVISTA_PARTO > '2017-04-01' 
AND visite.DATA_VISITA  = 
(SELECT MAX(visite_2.DATA_VISITA) 
FROM anagrafe_2 
LEFT JOIN visite_2 USING(NUMERO_AZIENDALE) 
WHERE anagrafe_2.NUMERO_AZIENDALE = anagrafe.NUMERO_AZIENDALE)
```